# Разбиение на интервалы дат

Tags: python, python-3.x, алгоритм, дата

Пару дней назад участвовал в квалификации [Yandex Cup 2020](https://yandex.ru/cup) (по ее итогам все-таки пробился в финал). Первой из шести задач была задача "Разбиение на интервалы дат". Вот ее условие:

Миша работает в команде Яндекс.Маркета, которая предоставляет производителям товаров аналитику о продажах. Сейчас Миша разбирается с периодизацией: нужно собирать данные по дням, неделям, месяцам, кварталам и годам. От клиентов приходят запросы, в которых указан период детализации и интервал: начальная и конечная даты. Так что первоначально Мише нужно разбить интервал на периоды. Так, если клиент хочет данные с `2020-01-10` по `2020-03-25` с детализацией по месяцам, то ему вернутся данные за три периода: c `2020-01-10` по `2020-01-31`, с `2020-02-01` по `2020-02-29` и с `2020-03-01` по `2020-03-25`. Помогите Мише, а то ему еще диплом писать надо!

Всего нужно поддержать пять видов временных интервалов:

- `WEEK` — неделя с понедельника по воскресенье.
- `MONTH` — месяц.
- `QUARTER` — интервалы в три месяца: январь — март, апрель — июнь, июль — сентябрь, октябрь — декабрь.
- `YEAR` — год c 1 января по 31 декабря.
- `LAST_SUNDAY_OF_YEAR` — интервал, начинающийся в последнее воскресенье декабря.

### Формат ввода

В первой строке дан типа интервала `type` — строка, принимающая одно из следующих значений: `WEEK`, `MONTH`, `QUARTER`, `YEAR`, `LAST_SUNDAY_OF_YEAR`. Во второй строке через пробел даны начальная и конечная даты `start` и `end` (`start ≤ end` ) в формате `yyyy-MM-dd`. Гарантируется, что обе даты лежат в промежутке с 1 января 2000 года по 31 декабря 3999 года включительно.

### Формат вывода

В первой строке ответа выведите одно целое число `N` — количество промежутков. В последующих `N` строках на `i`-й строке выведите через пробел дату начала и конца `i`-го промежутка в формате `yyyy-MM-dd`. Промежутки должны выводиться в порядке возрастания начальной даты.

### Пример 1

**Ввод:**

```
MONTH
2020-01-10 2020-03-25
```

**Вывод:**

```
3
2020-01-10 2020-01-31
2020-02-01 2020-02-29
2020-03-01 2020-03-25
```

#### Пример 2

**Ввод:**

```
WEEK
2020-01-26 2020-03-23
```

**Вывод:**

```
10
2020-01-26 2020-01-26
2020-01-27 2020-02-02
2020-02-03 2020-02-09
2020-02-10 2020-02-16
2020-02-17 2020-02-23
2020-02-24 2020-03-01
2020-03-02 2020-03-08
2020-03-09 2020-03-15
2020-03-16 2020-03-22
2020-03-23 2020-03-23
```

#### Пример 3

**Ввод:**

```
LAST_SUNDAY_OF_YEAR
2018-01-01 2021-01-01
```

**Вывод:**

```
4
2018-01-01 2018-12-29
2018-12-30 2019-12-28
2019-12-29 2020-12-26
2020-12-27 2021-01-01
```

А теперь перейдем к коду. Написал его с использованием стандартных модулей, прогнал на стандартных тестах и... получил `Wrong Answer` на 8 (скрытом) тесте. Тесты так и не открыли, разбора задач нету, а ошибку найти хочется.

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
import calendar

result = []
interval = input()
start, end = [datetime.strptime(date, '%Y-%m-%d') for date in input().split()]
if start == end:
    print(1)
    print(start.strftime('%Y-%m-%d') + ' ' + end.strftime('%Y-%m-%d'))
else:
    while True:
        after = start
        if interval == 'MONTH':
            after = after.replace(
                day=list(calendar.monthrange(start.year, start.month))[1])
        elif interval == 'WEEK':
            while after.isoweekday() != 7:
                after += timedelta(days=1)
        elif interval == 'YEAR':
            after = after.replace(day=31, month=12)
        elif interval == 'QUARTER':
            while not ((after.day == 31 and after.month == 3)
                       or (after.day == 30 and after.month == 6)
                       or (after.day == 30 and after.month == 9)
                       or (after.day == 31 and after.month == 12)):
                after += timedelta(days=1)
        elif interval == 'LAST_SUNDAY_OF_YEAR':
            after = after.replace(day=31, month=12)
            while after.isoweekday() != 6:
                after -= timedelta(days=1)
            if after < start:
                after = after.replace(day=31, month=12, year=after.year + 1)
                while after.isoweekday() != 6:
                    after -= timedelta(days=1)
        if after < end:
            result.append(start.strftime('%Y-%m-%d') +
                          ' ' + after.strftime('%Y-%m-%d'))
            start = after
            start += timedelta(days=1)
        else:
            result.append(start.strftime('%Y-%m-%d') +
                          ' ' + end.strftime('%Y-%m-%d'))
            break

    print(len(result))
    print('\n'.join(result))
```

Надеюсь на вашу помощь :)

Comment: Ассертов бы добавить проверочных сразу )

Comment: Да я вам тест кейсов накидаю, не справитесь :) Вы вообще думали об ошибочном вводе? А о специальном вводе, когда попадает на високосные годы?

Comment: @0andriy что вы подразумеваете под ошибочным вводом? Входные данные строго регламентированы.

Comment: @0andriy насчет високосных годов: код доходит до конца года (каким бы он ни был -- тут за нас работает `datetime`), так что возможностей для возникновения ошибок конкретно в этом месте я не вижу.

Comment: Таймзоны учитывали? А ссылка на *стандартные тесты* есть?

Comment: Как насчёт вывода 0 интервалов? Вот это я имел ввиду под ошибочным вводом. (На ум приходит запрос про последнее воскресенье года, но при этом даты одинаковые)

Comment: @0andriy неа... https://i.imgur.com/rYVVzCu.png

Comment: Так вы меня не поняли, возможно от вас ожидают вывода 0 в некоторых случаях

Comment: @0andriy во второй строке вывода второго примера  указан интервал из одного дня. Увы, вы неправы.

Comment: Там ввод не из одного дня.

Comment: @0andriy и что? Это доказывает возможность существования промежутков из одного дня, этого достаточно.

Comment: А что вы от меня-то хотите? тестов нет, какую ошибку вы предлагаете найти?

Comment: @0andriy вот я и пытаюсь понять, где она, аналитическим путем.

Comment: обязательно использовать только встроенные модули? Можно, например, Pandas использовать?

Comment: а по времени у них были ограничения? `WEEK 2000-01-01 3999-12-31` выполняется банально дольше необходимого из-за того что дни по единичке прибавляешь... ну и тоже самое про квартал...

Comment: @Fat-Zer нет, там был бы не `Wrong Answer`, а `Time Limit`.

Comment: @MaxU мне нужно найти ошибку в текущем решении, а не написать новое.

Comment: @ДаниилЧижевский, OK, удачи!

Comment: Я попробовал на с++ это сделать по глупости. Сидел и тупил. На c# это делается на раз-два. Задача мне показалась с подковыркой. Я думал что есть единое решение для всех периодов. Но похоже нет.